# Error on checking JIRA connectivity while installing its-jira plugin in gerrit

Tags: jira, gerrit, jira-rest-api

We're trying to setup gerrit v3.4.4 along with its-jira plugin. But during init stage of gerrit site, where the plugin checks for JIRA connectivity, we are getting Error:  **java.io.IOException: Request failed: https://example1.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo/ - 403 - null**

However, curl request to https://example1.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo works fine.

We're running openjdk version "11.0.14.1" on Centos 7.  Any pointers on fixing this error will be really helpful.
Thank you..!

Comment: I was using incorrect login password for jira account. After updating the correct password in etc/secure.config,   jira connectivity worked fine.

Comment: So it's better to remove your question.